# Gets sets the order in which the trigger and the update operation are executed

Tags: sql-server

I created a Insert & Update trigger and everything is fine but the trigger is not firing.
I used the database GUI View Facets and it indicating UpdateOrder = None. 
Msg: "Gets sets the order in which the trigger and the update operation are executed"
Any thoughts?

Comment: Huh??? Can you post your trigger and why you think it isn't firing? Probably need the ddl for the base table as well.

Comment: Why did you create a new question for this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494424/this-script-is-dml-trigger-intended-to-update-table-but-the-trigger-is-not-firin

Comment: "Any thoughts?" is not a real question. Nor do these options affect or disable the execution of a trigger. You are grasping at straws and avoiding the real issues, whatever they may be.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE [ OR ALTER ] TRIGGER [ schema_name . ]trigger_name   
ON { table | view }   
[ WITH <dml_trigger_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
{ FOR | AFTER | INSTEAD OF }   
{ [ INSERT ] [ , ] [ UPDATE ] [ , ] [ DELETE ] }   
[ WITH APPEND ]  
[ NOT FOR REPLICATION ]   
AS { sql_statement  [ ; ] [ ,...n ] | EXTERNAL NAME <method specifier [ ; ] > }
```

You forget to set FOR, AFTER or INTEAD OF! I didn't know this was possible.

For further help, please give us the SQL used.