# This script is DML Trigger intended to update table but the trigger is not firing. Any thoughts?

Tags: sql-server

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ProviderOffice_UPDATE]
ON [dbo].[ProviderOffice]
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
        SET ANSI_PADDING ON;

        UPDATE ProviderOffice
        SET ProviderOffice.LastUpdateID = USER_NAME(),
            ProviderOffice.LastUpdateDateTime = GETDATE()           
        FROM ProviderOffice
        JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                      AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.Provider_HEUID
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Provider_HEUID, LocationNBR 
                   FROM INSERTED
                   WHERE EligibilityFlag = 1 
                     AND INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 IN (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16) 
                     AND INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 IN (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16) 
                     AND INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 IN (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16))
            UPDATE ProviderOffice
            SET EligibilityFlag = 2
            FROM ProviderOffice 
            JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                          AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.LocationNbr
            WHERE (inserted.EligibilityFlag = 1
                  AND INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16) 
                  AND INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16) 
                  AND INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 in (2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16))
         ELSE
             IF EXISTS (SELECT Provider_HEUID, LocationNBR 
                        FROM INSERTED
                        WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 1 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 3 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 5 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 7 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 9 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 11 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 13 OR 
                              INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1= 15)
                 UPDATE ProviderOffice
                 SET EligibilityFlag = 1
                 FROM ProviderOffice
                 JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                               AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.LocationNbr
                 WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 1 OR 
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 3 OR 
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 5 OR  
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 7 OR   
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 9 OR 
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 11 OR 
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 13 OR 
                       INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 15
        ELSE
            IF EXISTS (SELECT Provider_HEUID, LocationNBR 
                       FROM INSERTED
                       WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 1 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 3 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 5 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 7 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 9 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 11 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 13 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 15)
               UPDATE ProviderOffice
               SET EligibilityFlag = 1
               FROM ProviderOffice
               JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                             AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.LocationNbr
               WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 1 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 3 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 5 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 7 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 9 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 11 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 13 
                  OR INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 15
        ELSE
            IF EXISTS (SELECT Provider_HEUID, LocationNBR 
                       FROM INSERTED
                       WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 1 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 3 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 5 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 7 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 9 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 11 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 13 OR 
                             INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 15)
               UPDATE ProviderOffice
               SET EligibilityFlag = 1
               FROM ProviderOffice
               JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                             AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.LocationNbr
               WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 1 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 3 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 5 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 7 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 9 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 11 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 13 OR 
                     INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 15
     ELSE
        IF EXISTS (SELECT Provider_HEUID, LocationNBR 
                   FROM INSERTED
                   WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 0 AND 
                         INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 0 AND 
                         INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 0)
           UPDATE ProviderOffice
           SET EligibilityFlag = 3
           FROM ProviderOffice
           JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                         AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.LocationNbr
           WHERE INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode1 = 0 AND 
                 INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode2 = 0 AND 
                 INSERTED.OfficeTypeCode3 = 0 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

This script is for my precious question on "trigger not firing". Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you know this isn't firing? And what it the point of the try/catch block? Anytime an error occurs in a trigger it will rollback the transaction. Having explicit transactions in a trigger is not a good idea because if you have calling code that is utilizing a transaction the trancount will be off and cause lots of other issues.

Answer (score 0):

This block of code is the most likely problem:

```
    UPDATE ProviderOffice
    SET ProviderOffice.LastUpdateID = USER_NAME(),
        ProviderOffice.LastUpdateDateTime = GETDATE()           
    FROM ProviderOffice
    JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
                  AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.Provider_HEUID
```

Everywhere else, the JOIN on inserted is

```
JOIN inserted ON ProviderOffice.Provider_HEUID = inserted.Provider_HEUID
              AND ProviderOffice.LocationNbr = inserted.LocationNbr
```

Is there some reason, other than cerebral cramping, that the first query tries to join `ProviderOffice.LocationNbr` to `inserted.Provider_HEUID`

In other words, most of the trigger is probably working, but your updates to the LastUpdateId and LastUpdateDateTime are not going in correctly.

**NOTE:** This is a major reason why updates to last updated and who last updated should either be in the code, or in a separate trigger from one that does conditional updates as above. If at least one of the conditions above should be true, then the updates to user and update time should be done in each conditional block. Yes, the code is repeated, but you then have the conditional update + user/time update run simultaneously.